# ubuntu installation stuck on splash screen

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hp, plymouth

I recently bought a HP-spectre ap0023dx-this link-, but I am having troubles with ubuntu installation. As soon as my system gets into splash screen, the screen will freeze, and also keyboard does not work at all. I have tried all the possible ways, found in my search for the same problem, but none of them worked, including: disable the fast boot, disable secure boot, add "nomodeset" and "acpi=off" in grub boot menu.

I appreciate if you can share with me your knowledge and information, if you had the same experience, or know the origin of this problem
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Bootline arguments to boot in Ryzen 2700u = Grub menu= e = linus line = CRTL + X to save and exit.

> 1. **ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 spec_store_bypass_disable=prctl1**
> 2. **ivrs_ioapic[33]=00:00.1**
> 3. **iommu=soft**
> 4. **ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[33]=00:00.1**

One or the other, they all work. The third only allows to compile kernels higher than 4.19. **You must add a space** at the end of the **linux line** and then type iommu=soft + CTRL + X to save and launch the installer.

All Linux ISO images won’t boot here,without this tweak.  They should work for Intel 8th gen. Secure boot is always enabled here, even for the clean install. Never touch fast startup and only one parameter is disabled in BIOS: Boot order + all Windows stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I did the following in my grub file

"linux /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 spec_store_bypass_disable=prctl1 ivrs_ioapic[33]=00:00.1 iommu=soft "

but still I am facing this error:

"package temperature above threshhold, cpu clock throttled
stdin: invalid argument
pwconv: failed to change the mode of /etc/passwd- to 0600"
is that a hardware incompatibility?

Comment: You must try them one at a time.